# Regex to check MM:SS

Tags: regex

I need to validate a MM:SS format figure.  There is no hours figure so the minutes value can go over 60.    I almost have this.  I currently have:

```
^[0-1]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$
```

However if the minutes go over two figures this won't make a match.   Ie 123:59

Can anyone confirm what the most economical way of adding support for a number of any size on the left size of the colons character ?

Comment: Any number of one or more digits? `\d+`/`[0-9]+`. `^[0-9]+:[0-5][0-9]$`

Comment: Hi Wiktor thanks but I just tried that in a testing tool I have and it doesn't match anything in the mm side any more

Comment: It works on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cJ2Ne5/1)

Comment: Ah ok but that doesn't have \d+.  I was testing with that too.   Well thanks indeed the one there does work.  if you want some points feel free to write up as an answer ;)

Comment: `\d` is the same as `[0-9]`. Either can be used but the latter is more versatile. https://regex101.com/r/xgaJYz/1